# Setting the value of a hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, hidden

The idea: I'm setting the value of an input with type="hidden" via regular Javascript or jQuery.

The issue: neither jQuery nor document.getElementById will find the hidden input, even though I'm absolutely sure the selector is correct and there are no conflicting elements.

The code:
I can't really post much of it, because it's full of rather complicated PHP that confuses me when I just look at it.

Here's the javascript:

```
$("#" + input.id.substr(0,2) + "_budget_hidden").val(budg_total);
```

Note: **there's nothing wrong with the selector**, and the "input" is a different element that I'm using to reference the hidden.

Here's the HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="s<?=$step_counter?>_budget_hidden" 
       id="s<?=$step_counter?>_budget_hidden" value="0" />
```

The code is kind of out of context, but it's more of a general problem with Javascript than a syntactical error. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `$("#" + input.id.substr(0,2) + "_budget_hidden").val(budg_total);` you take two chars before the first underscore in your hidden id. However your hidden id have only one char 's'

**EDIT**

Ok the `<?= ?>` was hidden before the question edit.

Do you call your script after the body onload event?
EX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#" + input.id.substr(0,2) + "_budget_hidden").bind("keyPressed",function(){
        $("#" + input.id.substr(0,2) + "_budget_hidden").val(budg_total);
     }
});
```

Comment: It's being called in the onkeypress event for the "input" variable that I reference in the jQuery selector.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying.
The event is defined inline, on the input itself.
onkeypress="updateDifferences(this)"
So that shouldn't be an issue, in theory.

Comment: @Will how can you have a onkeypress on hidden input? they are not shown.

Comment: The onkeypress is on a different text input, which calls a function that changes the hidden input.

Answer (score 1):

**FYI:** We can get the hidden input value using jQuery, even we can also edit any hidden input value using jQuery.

I think your way of getting the hidden value using 'substr' method is causing some problem. You are using like `substr(0, 2)` so are sure that the variable `$step_variable` is a single digit number, otherwise your code will not return correct result.

I am giving some sample code below, check it once.

Here's the javascript:

```
    var input_id = $("hidden_val").attr("id").substr(1);
    $("#" + input_id + "_budget_hidden").val(budg_total);
```

Here's the HTML:

```
    input type="hidden" class="hidden_val" name="s_budget_hidden" id="s" value="0"
```

I think this will help you. Let me know if you are not following this flow to solve your issue.

Comment: That is an excellent point, could have caused some potential errors there. I just decided to use explode instead and avoided some nasty trouble.
However, the particular input I was experimenting on had a step_counter value of 2, so it wouldn't have mattered anyway. I'm not 110% convinced the selector is right -- I've echoed it out and it shows exactly the same as the id of the hidden input I'm trying to access. It's the jQuery/Javascript, not the selector itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think that input.id.substr(0,2) says to start at the start of the string, take 2 characters and use that.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp

Try using Firebug to see what the result of that method call is.

Comment: Yes, that is what the substring does. As I said, it's a rather complicated system taken out of context, but I guarantee that the particular selector is accurate and corresponds to a hidden form element in the page.

I've used Firebug, and there are no errors or warnings.