# How to return a value for an unchecked checkbox with django

Tags: html, django, django-forms

I am trying to change a value in db that is controlled via a checkbox, if a review for the item exist already i am populating the fields with it . Currently I have a hidden field and then a jQuery Mobile checkbox controlling this:

models.py:

`fave = models.BooleanField()`

ModelForms face Class:

`'fave': HiddenInput(attrs={'value' : 'False'}),`

and my review form:

```
{% if review.fave == 'True' %}
    <div class="ui-block-c">
        <input type="checkbox" name="fave" id="checkbox-1" class="custom" checked="checked"/>
        <label for="checkbox-1">fave</label>
    </div>
{% else %}
     <div class="ui-block-c">
        <input type="checkbox" name="fave" id="checkbox-1" class="custom" />
        <label for="checkbox-1">fave</label>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

The hidden field is rendered to the browser as such:

`<input type="hidden" name="fave" value="True" id="id_fave">`

While I could make the checkbox a non-hidden field, the task make it fit the way its supposed to with django and jQuery Mobile looks daunting.

Several posts listed solutions:
[Setting the value of a hidden input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197346/setting-the-value-of-a-hidden-input)

, but nothing seems to work the way I want. I cannot seem to override the `value = True`.

Is there something simple I am missing? Am I going about it all wrong?

Comment: I think you are trying to set strings to a boolean

Comment: I was concerned about that as well. I tried  `value = False` without quotes and then in `default=False` (this gave me a error). How would I go about flipping that boolean?

Comment: `{% if review.fave == 'True' %}`
I don't think this can be true with fave as a bool.

Comment: That is definittly correct. I was experimenting with some other way of doing in and left that in. I used initially `{% if review.fave %}` to verify existence and then if is existed check the field. its sounds crude, but perhaps I should try a char field, and use the checkbox to modify the value. Seems hackish though :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
'fave': CheckboxInput(attrs={'style':'display:none'})
```

Comment: Thanks srusskih, I don't think that will work because the the checkbox I need to clear will still be on, just hidden which is the same problem I have now.